# I wanted to create a simple mobile online game for me and my mates. How should I handle the networking?

Tags: networking, mobile, unity-networking

I've made a few simple games and one multiplayer game where you connect through LAN but for this one I wanted to learn something new. I have the game concept working on my computer, it's just waiting for the networking.

I was looking to create networking similar to mobile online quiz games, where:
- you use your Store account as the game account
- you are not restricted to LAN or same WiFi network, but rather everything goes through an external server
- you have a Friends list,Recently Played list where you can see who's online right now
- you can invite a random player to a match or search for particular player to play with them/add them to your Friends list

Something like that. I don't know if you can host servers for a match on mobile devices, or how feasible it would be, given mobile internet isn't free, but it would make for a nice addition if the external server was only for handling information about who's online.

I'm working in Unity btw. so any recommendation for package from Asset Store is welcomed

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/).